# run "rosdep install -r --from-paths ." error when I install iai_kinect2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I was run `rosdep install -r --from-paths .`, some errors show me as following:

```
turtlebot@turtlebot-HP-ZBook-14-G2:~/catkin_ws/src/iai_kinect2$ rosdep install -r --from-paths .

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved

to system dependencies:

kinect2_viewer: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [kinect2_bridge]

kinect2_calibration: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [kinect2_bridge]

kinect2_bridge: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [kinect2_registration]

Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...

All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

Some assistes show as following writing by author:

rosdep will output errors on not being able to locate [kinect2_bridge] and [depth_registration]. That is fine because they are all part of the iai_kinect2 package and rosdep does not know these packages.

what should I do, my rosdep can just know these packages.
Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237451/run-%22rosdep-install--r---from-paths-.%22-error-when-i-install-iai_kinect2/) by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2016-06-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-20**:
Please don't post updates as answers. *Only* post *answers* if you are actually *answering* your own question. I've merged your answer as an update into your OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would think this is what `--ignore-src` is meant for.

---

Edit:

> following you, Should I run the command which is " rosdep install --ignore-src" ?

No, the full command should be:

```
rosdep install --from-paths ~/catkin_ws/src/iai_kinect2 --ignore-src -r
```

That will make `rosdep` look for packages in the `~/catkin_ws/src/iai_kinect2` directory, gather all the dependencies, check which you have installed, which are missing, then subtract all packages that it finds in `~/catkin_ws/src/iai_kinect2` (because of `--ignore-src`), and then install everything that is still missing.

> I am running, but terminal show some errors to me:

> ```
> rosdep: error: no packages or stacks specified
> ```

Well, yes. You give it no path and no package name, so it can't do anything for you.

Please also check the output of `rosdep --help`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on 2016-06-20**:
following you, Should I run the command which is " rosdep install --ignore-src" ?

I am running, but terminal show some errors to me:

rosdep: error: no packages or stacks specified

**Comment by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on 2016-06-20**:
I find that this errors can be ignore, however, OpenCL is not optional but integrant when install iai_kinect2.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-21**:
This is a new question, unrelated to your earlier one. I advise you to open a new one.

Also (and for the last time): please don't post *answers* if you are not *answering* your question. ROS Answers is not a normal forum, but an [askbot](http://answers.ros.org/help/) site. It works differently.

**Comment by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on 2016-06-22**:
I find that this errors can be ignore, however, OpenCL is not optional but integrant when install iai_kinect2.

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-17**:
Hi, openCL is actually optional as you can choose to either use openGL, openCL or CPU. You may read the FAQs on https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2#dependencies.

Check the website: If one of them works, try out the one that worked with kinect2_bridge: